# Coinimp http api withdraw

Tags: php-curl

I'm trying to write the whole for coinimp a payout for the api v2.0. Unfortunately, I always get back only one empty issue.
maybe one of you can help me and tell you what the problem is here.

```
$fields = array(
        "site-key" => 'c085da9be5ba47309d3805b3fe0e0e66adcda4f6f5041e8e6d21d6bd2abc60ce',
        "user" => $this->user,
        "amount" => $this->KontoExtern
    );
    $fields_string = '';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/user/withdraw');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = self::X_API_ID;
    $headers[] = self::X_API_KEY;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $ausgabe = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    echo 'Ausgabe:'.$ausgabe.'<br>';

    curl_close ($ch);

    $aus = json_decode($ausgabe);
    return $aus;
```

can someone help me here and say where the problem lies?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

the coinIMP API documentation realy is a mess i found this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727409/how-to-use-curl-php) and it works

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/user/balance?site-key=WEBSITE-ID&user=USER-ID",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"cache-control: no-cache",
"x-api-id: PUBLIC-ID",
"x-api-key: SECRET-ID"
),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

this code is easy to edit to make it work for you !!

1. change CURLOPT_URL value to: http://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/user/withdraw
2. change CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET" to "POST"
3. Add CURLOPT_POST => 2 to the curl_setopt_array
4. Add CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>""site-key=***value***&user=***value***&amount=***value***

i know this isn't a direct answer to your qluestion but anyway it works :)
*note: this will withdrawl Webchain, i haven't tryt Monero jet*

Comment: It is very easy to implement but like what i said it is not working, https://www.coinimp.com/documentation/http-api#user-withdraw

they are not even trying to fix something so sad for us.