# How to use curl php

Tags: php, curl

I desperately want to use an API that asks curl. I do not know anything at all. So I teter to document myself, but I do not understand everything.

Here is what the API says:

All requests must be provided with unique API keys, which you can generate in dashboard. X-API-ID (public) and X-API-KEY (private) parameters. For example:

```
curl -L http://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/hashes
    -H 'X-API- 
ID:7e26bb94aa2ce44e6e16aca6ae6d28c7f0157b5ccd7a82f86bbbe8d835effd71'
    -H 'X-API- 
KEY:5112486af64b2f97bd3742c4153cee32452549491480cfd164b336720b82a84d'
```

Here is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

$opts = array(


CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/hashes',
CURLOPT_HEADER => array(
        'X-API- 
ID:0cd6929b8e34e2cc686eb50bef6a909c4898125b5105221fbfe48a43b038d9ff',
        'X-API- 
KEY:61dbf2d44abd138bad67c7876dcac0f58b2f08c8bbb91108c7c0984fe7b5f207',
        )


);

curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);

print_r($response);
```

Here is my result:

```
 HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Date: Sat, 16 Feb 2019 20:19:44 GMT Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Cache-Control: max-age=3600 Expires: Sat, 16 Feb 2019 21:19:44 GMT Location: https://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/reward Server: cloudflare CF-RAY: 4aa2b5fd8a25c83d-AMS 1
```

Please can you help me ?

Comment: Please use code formatting next time.

Comment: I guess, you need something like `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Answer (score 1):

CoinImp is an absolute mess; I worked with them briefly on a client project and quickly came to dislike their service.  You're receiving a 301 response, which indicates that the resource you're requesting is no longer at that address.  In the response it appears to give you the new endpoint:

https://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/reward

I would try reformatting your request towards that endpoint.  Otherwise, this would be a question for CoinImp support.

Comment: With api v1.0, method get : https://www.coinimp.com/api/v1/reward?public=61dbf2d44abd138bad67c7876dcac0f58b2f08c8bbb91108c7c0984fe7b5f207&private=0cd6929b8e34e2cc686eb50bef6a909c4898125b5105221fbfe48a43b038d9ff

Comment: @MickaëlCoureau the response there indicates you have bad API keys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your problem, but i suggest use to use Postman Api Development Environment.
https://www.getpostman.com/

You should enter URL where you will make the request, username, password and additional parameters specified by API provider.
You can test API also you can generate script in different programming languages without writing a single row of code.

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Replace WEBSITE-ID with the ID you used for miner script.
And replace PUBLIC-ID and SECRET-ID, also USER-ID.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/user/balance?site-key=WEBSITE-ID&user=USER-ID",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "x-api-id: PUBLIC-ID",
    "x-api-key: SECRET-ID"
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

Good luck.